# Function to check for largest prime factor returning returning 0 when using large numbers c++

Tags: c++

This is for the third problem in Project Euler.
I suspect that it only returns 0 because I assigned 0 to the 'returnum' variable on initialization. My code works fine in smaller numbers, but it isn't working for a large number (600851475143) which is needed to get the correct answer.

Is this for the size of int? If so what data type should I use?

Here is my code:

```
int problem3(long int num) {
    long int returnum;
    for (int i = 2; i < num; ++i) {
        if (num % i == 0 && primecheck(i)) {
           returnum = i;
        }
    }
    return returnum;
}
```

And this is my 'primecheck' function:

```
bool primecheck(long int num) {
     for (int i = 2; i <= num / 2; ++i) {
         if (num % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Edit: I have tried to change the datatype but when I do, it just doesn't respond, showing an empty console for a few minutes, then crashing.

Comment: use `long long`

Comment: 600851475143 written in binary has 40 digits.

Comment: @TemaniAfif It just shows blank

Comment: If you replace `int` with a suitable integral type, your program will take a rather long time to finish. Prepare for waiting for an hour or more.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum value for a variable of type int is 2147483647, whereas the max value of float is : 3.40282e+38 or 0x1.fffffep+127. You could use double also.

Comment: Floating-point numbers for factorization? This is noit going to end well...

Answer (score 0):

```
long long problem3(long long num) {
long long returnum;
for (long long i = 2; i < num; ++i) {
    if (num % i == 0 && primecheck(i)) {
       returnum = i;
    }
}
return returnum;
}
```

And this is my 'primecheck' function:

```
bool primecheck(long long num) {
     for (long long i = 2; i <= num / 2; ++i) {
         if (num % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

[Fundamental Types (C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc953fe1.aspx)

tested! OK!
VS2017

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>

bool primecheck(long long num);
long long problem3(long long num);

bool primecheck(long long num) {
    for (long long i = 2; i <= num / 2; ++i) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

long long problem3(long long num) {
    long long returnum;
    for (long long i = 2; i < num; ++i) {
        if (num % i == 0 && primecheck(i)) {
            returnum = i;
        }
        if (i % 100000 == 0) {
            printf("tick - %lld\n", i);
        }
    }
    return returnum;
}


int main()
{
    printf("out number %lld\n", problem3(600851475143));
    return 0;
}
```

[32 037 210 000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH7i3.png) - screenshot 10 000 000 per/sec . 
(in this moment > (long)2^32)
and what you want with this program? wait 65K sec? (18 hours)
may be need use math algorithm for best time ?

Comment: Still doesn't work. If I change the datatype it just is blank in the console.

Comment: im tested it. its ok